# CSS table-cell 100% width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a layout like this:

[image: layout]

this is what I have so far:

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="top">
    <div id="top">100% width and  45px height </div>
</div>
<div id="middle">
    <div id="middleleft">Middle Left 20%</div>
    <div id="middlecenter">Center 60%</div>
    <div id="middleright">Middle Right 20%</div>
</div>
<div id="bottom">
    <div id="bottom">100% width and 30% height</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#top{
    width:???;
    height: 45px;
}
#bottom {
    width: ???;
    height: 30%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jn6x6/

But I cannot make the top and buttom take the 100%.

Is this the right approach or should I try something different?

Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Jn6x6/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
#wrapper #middle {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

to the CSS of your JsFiddle.

See http://jsfiddle.net/Jn6x6/1/

Comment: Thanks Alohci this does exactly what I want :)

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
#top,
#bottom {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Not do what you need?

Comment: It doesn't work for him, because he is using `display: table;`, `display: table-cell;` to create the layout.

Comment: If you try it on the fiddle that I posted I does not do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

At
     < div id="top">
         < div id="top">100% width and  45px height < /div>
     < /div>

try to give the 2nd id the name "top_box" and give the 1st id (#top) a width of 100% and the 2nd one (#top_box) a width of *inherit*

Also, try testing your HTML code in a newly created HTML file (example.html) and open it in a browser.